# Using Google Visualization API in google sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-sites

I am new to JS and GAS and have managed fairly well so far. I am ,however, getting lost when it comes to utilizing HTML with the JS.  I would like to use the timeline function of google's visualization API and using data from either sites or sheets I would like to populate the chart.

Google visualization API [>>HERE<<](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline)

Google chart service using DoGet [>>HERE<<](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/)

The second link shows the implementation, it seems that I can't embed these created charts on my site then?

How do I combine the HTML service with the JS an display a timeline chart on a google site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: UI Deprecated]

The UI Service was deprecated only a few days ago, on Dec. 11, 2014

[Google Documentation - UI Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service)

Here is a step-by-step explanation of what you need to do:

### Create an Apps Script that is Attached to your Site

- In your Google Site - Click the button with the Gear icon
- Choose MANAGE SITE
- Click the APPS SCRIPT selection
- Click the ADD NEW SCRIPT button
- Choose SCRIPT AS WEB APP

Replace the code in the `doGet()` function, so it looks like this:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

Save it.
Give the project a name.

### Create an index.html file

- Choose FILE, NEW, HTML file

Enter the following into the HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["timeline"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
        dataTable.addRows([
          [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 29), new Date(1797, 2, 3) ],
          [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 3),  new Date(1801, 2, 3) ],
          [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 3),  new Date(1809, 2, 3) ]]);

        chart.draw(dataTable);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="timeline" style="width: 900px; height: 180px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

- Save the new index.html file

### Publish your Apps Script

- Click PUBLISH
- Click Deploy As Web App
- Save a new version if there is no version
- Click UPDATE at the bottom

### Add an Apps Script Gadget to your Sites Page

- Go back to your Sites page.
- Click the EDIT Page button with the icon of a pencil
- Click the INSERT menu
- Choose Apps Script
- Choose a Script
- Click the SELECT Button

Save all your changes.

You should get something that looks like this:

[image: Timeline Chart in Sites]

Now that you have the `.gs` code and the HTML set up, you need modify the JavaScript in the SCRIPT tag of the HTML file.

You need to run a `google.script.run` API to trigger another function in the `.gs` file that will go out and get your data.

[Google Documentation - Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Take a look at that documentation, and learn what it does.

The new code in the index.html file will be something like this:

```
<script>
  function onSuccess(importedData) {
    dataTable.addRows([importedData]);
    chart.draw(dataTable);
    alert('Your data has been loaded');
  }

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
      .retrieveChartData();
</script>
```

The hard coded data will be replaced with code.  This is the hard coded data that must be removed and changed to something else:

```
    dataTable.addRows([
      [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 29), new Date(1797, 2, 3) ],
      [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 3),  new Date(1801, 2, 3) ],
      [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 3),  new Date(1809, 2, 3) ]]);
```

You need to add another function to your `.gs` script file.  Something like this:

```
function retrieveChartData() {
  Logger.log('I was called!');
  //Get the data from your data source
  Code here
  var tableData = code here;
  //return the data
  return tableData;
}
```

Comment: When I am grabbing my data to be passed to the chart do I need to create an object for all of the data? That's what the dataTable.addRows looks like. Or can I pass variables from the .gs file to the html file?

Comment: See the `onSuccess` function. The  `onSuccess` function automatically receives whatever is returned from the function that is called by `google.script.run`.  The data that was hard coded is not an object, it's a two dimensional array.  You can pass an object from the `retrieveChartData()` function, but in the `onSuccess` function, you'd need to reformat the data to a two dimensional array.  If you get stuck on something specific, just post another question with code, and the line that is returning the unexpected result.  Use `Logger.log("Value is: " + variable);` statements and VIEW the LOG.